# Obtain a good, BIG/LARGE image in rich link preview in Telegram

Tags: html, telegram, facebook-opengraph

I saw a lot or request about rich link preview in Telegram, but this is specifically about "how to get a **BIG/LARGE** image" in the preview.

Let's take [this article](https://turbolab.it/newsletter-turbolab.it-1349/questa-settimana-tli-08-dicembre-2018-1812) on my site as example. It already has all of the OGs:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Questa settimana su TLI (08 dicembre 2018)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://turbolab.it/immagini/12483/max" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://turbolab.it/newsletter-turbolab.it-1349/questa-settimana-tli-08-dicembre-2018-1812" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Non hai tempo di leggerci tutti i giorni? nessun problema! ecco a te il riepilogo di quanto proposto da TurboLab.it nel corso della settimana in conclusione." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="it_IT" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="turbolab.it" />
```

Result: it works when the link is posted on Telegram, **but the image is small and floated right** even if the og:image ([this](https://turbolab.it/immagini/12483/max)) is 1000 px wide. I'd like to have it big, on it's own line.

Check this out (first entry is my site, the one I want to fix: note the small image, floated right. 2nd and 3rd is the result I want as shown by a YouTube video and a Mashable article).

[image]

The 3 URLs used in the image above are:

1. https://turbolab.it/newsletter-turbolab.it-1349/questa-settimana-tli-08-dicembre-2018-1812
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6eHY537Cao
3. https://mashable.com/article/xiaomi-48-megapixel-camera/?europe=true&utm_cid=hp-r-1#cR2kG7X_naqO

richpreview.com isn't helpful, because it preview the image as "small" on all of the theree ([one](https://richpreview.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fturbolab.it%2Fnewsletter-turbolab.it-1349%2Fquesta-settimana-tli-08-dicembre-2018-1812), [two](https://richpreview.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dy6eHY537Cao), [three](https://richpreview.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2Farticle%2Fxiaomi-48-megapixel-camera%2F%3Feurope%3Dtrue%26utm_cid%3Dhp-r-1%23cR2kG7X_naqO)).

Strange thing is: it works as expected on Facebook. [There](https://www.facebook.com/TurboLab.it/), I get big, wide images. It's perfect [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/TurboLabIt) too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 22):

Adding twitter meta tags fixed the issue for me

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{IMAGE URL}" />
```

Comment: Don't know why telegram uses twitter tags. Anyway, here is the twitter docs https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image

Comment: This is still true as of this comment's date.

Comment: It's possible that they only use those when `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` is added to your page.

Comment: Pay attention to `summary_large_image`. It is very important here.

Answer (score 6):

Telegram bases its preview images on Twitter sharing cards markup. You're missing the `summary_large_image` content. You need to add the following in addition to what you have:

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://turbolab.it/immagini/12483/max">
```

Once you've updated your markup, paste the share link in to Telegram's [Webpage Bot](https://t.me/WebpageBot) and choose *Update Preview* to clear Telegram's image cache and view the enlarged image.

Consult [Summary Card with Large Image](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image) on Twitter Developers for more info.

To further enrich your results with large images you could also create a [Telegram Instant View](https://instantview.telegram.org/). Note however Instant Views only appear for designated templates chosen by Telegram itself.

Example custom Instant View Template:

```
# enable for items in the post section
?path: /post/.+

# define required elements
title: //*[@itemprop="headline"]
body: //*[@itemprop="articleBody"]

# if cover exists, define images
?exists: //head/meta[@property="og:image"]/@content
cover: //head/meta[@property="og:image"]/@content
image_url: $cover/self::img/@src
```

Example meta tag for to allow joins to your channel from the Instant View:

```
<meta property="telegram_channel" content="turbolabit">
```

You may lose some visibility of your visitor metrics but your users will have a better experience reading and enjoying your site from within Telegram which translates into brand recognition.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Open Graph protocol `prefix`-attribute in your html tag:

```html
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Learn more about the Open Graph protocol at [ogp.me](https://ogp.me/).